# How to get value of a selected option from select tag and use it in WP_query to filter posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, metadata, isset

This is how I'm getting the value but how to use it in WP_Query so when I click Search to display let's say posts with Option 1 value?

I'm doing this but don't know if meta_value is the answer

```
$search_query=new Wp_Query($search_args);
$something=isset($_GET['something'])&&$_GET['something']?$_GET['something']:'';

if($something){
     $search_args['meta_value']=$something;
}

<select name="something" id="" class="" style="width: 100%;">
        <option value="Something">Something</option>
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you're posting that form then you need to use $_POST, not $_GET

Comment: filter posts by which field?

Comment: @Metalik So the posts should have a custom field so let's say I can compare 'something' with the custom field value like:    $search_args['meta_query'] = 
  array(
   'key'  => 'custom_field',
   'compare' => '=',
   'value'  => $something
  );

Comment: put wp query after search args.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `meta_key` and put your `Wp_Query` after assign the `$search_args`.
Check below working code for the same.

```
 $something=isset($_GET['something'])&&$_GET['something']?$_GET['something']:'';

if($something){
     $search_args['meta_value']=$something;
     $search_args['meta_key']='YOUR_META_LKEY'; // add your meta key here
 }
 $search_query=new Wp_Query($search_args);
 <select name="something" id="" class="" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="Something">Something</option>
    <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
 </select>
```